# Recommended data structure for Dictionary+List

Tags: delphi, generics

I am trying to optimize a piece of code that holds a bunch of relations betweens objects (pointers).

The situation is the following:

From a series of objects a series of drawings are generated:

> TElement (A) ---> generates zero, one or more TDrawing (B)

(Classes are not relevant, so i'll call them A and B)

The current implementation is made with a dictionary

> TDictionary< B, A>

so every object from class B comes from a unique A

But in order to identify all the objects of class B that belongs to a given object of class A this is very inefficient, as the dictionary need to be looped to find all the keys with a certain value.

The immediate solution is changing the data structure to the following:

> TDictonary < TElements, TList < TDrawing > >

which is not completely efficient as a lot of small memory allocations needs to be done when filling the dictionary and list.

I wonder if someone could give me a hint about a good implementation, I would be grateful!

(sorry for my English)

Comment: Why not add a list to TElement to store its TDrawing items?

Comment: Well, it's either `TList<T>` or `TArray<T>` I suspect. I doubt that you'll be able to avoid the dynamic overhead. I guess one way would be to wrap it all up in a small record that contained a small static array of drawings, and a reference to a list object or an array. Try to use the static array until it is full, and after that use the dynamic allocated containers. That way you would only incur dynamic allocation for large collections of drawings.

Comment: @StefanGlienke That's fine until you need to maintain multiple different sets of relations.

Comment: Seems you need something like Guava BiMap. Quick search gives bi-directional dictionary in Delphi Collections library https://github.com/ghquant/delphi-coll/blob/master/src/Library/Collections.BidiDictionaries.pas

Comment: @MBo Delphi Collections is not maintained anymore for quite some time - so please don't suggest it. Anyhow it was already excluded to use a multimap approach (which the dictionary with list as value is) because of memory allocations.

Comment: @Stefan Glienke Do you know another library with reliable bi-map support? I havent' checked your Spring4D, but bi-map is quite rare thing in another languages with much wider codebase...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. @StefanGlienke, as David says, i actually need to maintain multiple sets of relations (multiples images with different views of the same model).

Comment: @MBo Spring4d does - however I was not suggesting it because that will for sure cause quite some memory allocations.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: I would not rule it out. **Perhaps** it causes quite some memory allocations, and **perhaps** that could be a bottleneck, but simply ruling out something that **might** be slow (and might be not as slow as expected) is premature optimization, IMO. Small memory allocations can be pretty performant, and TList<> actually doesn't have to do them that often.It is not impossible that the (already necessary) small allocations of TElement and TDrawing objects far outweigh those required for the multi-map approach.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Small memory allocations are the expensive ones! And heap allocation is always slow. Especially using the Delphi default memory manager. Which doesn't scale. Static allocation and minimising heap allocations in bottlenecks is always a good performance boost.

Comment: @David: I am not so sure. ISTM that they can be pretty fast. But anyway, how many are there? One TList<> per TElement. The TElement and the TDrawings that are in the list must already exist. They are the real small memory allocations, and they must be allocated anyway. I agree that your idea of a record with a small static array and only creating a list if there are more than fit in the small array would probably be much better, but I would still not dismiss anything before I had profiled it.

Comment: @rudy Heap allocation is objectively slow and doesn't scale with the default memory manager. As somebody who writes performance sensitive code for a living I have lost track of the number of times when removing heap allocation has yielded significant benefits.

Comment: @David: I'm sure you have your experience with it, but still... how many small objects would have to be allocated, and how does that number compare to the number of small allocations required for the objects that must be allocated anyway?

Comment: We're taking the asker at their word that the allocations are a bottleneck. If that's the case then removing them will help. If they aren't a bottleneck then, we'll, it won't. Scaling is where you can really be burned though. Heap allocation and lots of threads can make hitherto trouble free code become a bottleneck. Amdahl's law. I have an 80 core machine. So it really doesn't take much before heap allocation kills you. Scalable memory manager helps but my policy is always to do that and reduce the heap allocation.

Comment: Actually my bottleneck is memory allocation, that's why I was trying to avoid creating lots of small TLists

Answer (score -1):

A quite ugly code but I have come out with this solution:

```
PLinks:TDictionary<TElement, TObject>;
```

where the values are either a single object or a list. When adding a value, if the key was not previously set, it is set to the object. Only when trying to add a second value for a key, the value is converted to a list.

```
procedure AddLink(const source:TElement; object:TDrawing);
var
  v:TObject;
  list:TList<TDrawing>;
begin
 if not PLinks.ContainsKey(source) then
    PLinks.Add(source, object)
 else begin
    v:=PLinks[source];
    if v is TList<TDrawing> then
      (valor as TList<TDrawing>).add(n)
    else begin // v is TDrawing
      list:=TList<TDrawing>.Create;
      list.Add(v as TDrawing); // adds previous unique item
      list.Add(object);
      PLinks[source]:=list;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And obviously when looping through the values, it must be checked if the value is a single object or a list.

It's not very elegant, mostly because compile time type checking is lost, but in terms of speed and memory savings it's ok.

Comment: I'd rather do what @DavidHeffernan said: have a record of some sort that contains a small static array (let's call it cache) of TDrawing, and a pointer to a list that is either nil or contains additional TDrawings. Small statci array could be, say, 4 elements or so. Depends on your needs. Do not try to stuff too much meaning into an existing TDictionary (value is either TDrawing or TList<Drawing>, etc.). Write your own glue objects and put those in the dictionary instead.